# How to ask Python to update the variables for YAML?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I want to get values from python to put them in YAML:

```
import ruamel.yaml

file_name = 'input.yml'
from ruamel.yaml.util import load_yaml_guess_indent

config, ind, bsi = load_yaml_guess_indent(open(file_name))

instances = config['instances']
print instances
instances['hostname'] = raw_input('What is the host name>>')
instances['syslog'] = raw_input ('what is the Syslog ip address>>')
instances['prefix'] = raw_input('What is the first prefix>>')
instances['prefix'] = raw_input ('what is the second address>>')
```

`input.yml`:

```
---
instances:
      hostname: <name>              # update with IP
      syslog: <ip>    # update with user name
      interfaces:
         - name: GigabitEthernet0/0
           prefix: <first prefix>        
         - name: GigabitEthernet0/1
           prefix: <second prefix>
```

host and syslog part is working but I could not make prefix working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
instances['prefix'] = raw_input('What is the first prefix>>')
instances['prefix'] = raw_input ('what is the second address>>')
```

is not working (and if it would, you would update the same thing twice). You need to take into account that `prefix` is a key on an element of sequence (Python `list`) that is the value for the key `interfaces`:

```
instances['interfaces'][0]['prefix'] = raw_input('What is the first prefix>>')
instances['interfaces'][1]['prefix'] = raw_input ('what is the second address>>')
```

Comment: @NANIS Next time if you run into a problem, please provide the text of the error that you are getting as well. Especially when you cannot provide your complete program which would make it impossible to generate the error for others.